Roblox Web API : Authentication failure 'Token Validation Failed' CSRF token provided
static async Task SendPostRequest()
{
    // Create an instance of HttpClient
    using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient())
    {
        // Specify the URL to which you want to send the POST request
        //string url = "https://privatemessages.roblox.com/v1/messages/send";
        string url = "https://auth.roblox.com/";

        HttpClientHandler handler = new HttpClientHandler();

        // Create a cookie container
        handler.CookieContainer = new CookieContainer();

        // Set the cookie for the specific website
        Uri uri = new Uri("https://roblox.com");
        handler.CookieContainer.Add(uri, new Cookie(".ROBLOSECURITY", "MY_SECURITY_COOKIE_HERE"));

        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("X-CSRF-TOKEN", "MY_TOKEN");

        // ignore this
        var postData = new FormUrlEncodedContent(new[]
        {
            new KeyValuePair<string, string>("userId", "2222602108"),
            new KeyValuePair<string, string>("subject", "hey"),
            new KeyValuePair<string, string>("body", "thank you for adding me as a friend"),
            new KeyValuePair<string, string>("recipientId", "2222602108"),
            new KeyValuePair<string, string>("replyMessageId", "0"),
            new KeyValuePair<string, string>("includePreviousMessage", "false")
        });

        // Send the POST request
        HttpResponseMessage response = await client.PostAsync(url, postData);

        // Check if the request was successful
        if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {
            // Read the response content as a string
            string responseContent = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

            // Output the response content
            Console.WriteLine("Response:");
            Console.WriteLine(responseContent);
        }
        else
        {
            // If the request was not successful, output the status code
            Console.WriteLine($"Error: {response.StatusCode}");
            Console.WriteLine("Response:");
            string responseContent = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            Console.WriteLine(responseContent);
        }
    }
}



I'm trying to get the ROBLOX web API to authenticate calls from C#,
I have a valid security cookie and CSRF token, but it still doesn't seem to want to authenticate me.
I've tried adding the CSRF token as both cookie and header before sending the request. I've also tried authenticating on several different endpoints.
EDIT:
@Yorick's response to the question helped tremendeously.
As it turns out, if you scrape a CSRF token from your browser to use it will not work, you have to send a request to https://auth.roblox.com/ with a valid .ROBLOSECURITY cookie and use the CSRF token provided in the header. Here's what I added to the code presented above in order to get the x-csrf-token.
HttpResponseMessage response = await client.PostAsync(url, postData);

if (response.Headers.TryGetValues("x-csrf-token", out var values))
{
    csrfToken = string.Join(",", values);
    Console.WriteLine("x-csrf-token recv: " + csrfToken);
}

This will get all the headers included in the response and set the csrfToken value to be used elsewhere in the application.
But I should note that, despite using this method, I still cannot get it to work on APIs other than the auth API. For reference, here's a list of the Roblox Web API's Endpoints.
The API I've been testing it on is included in the example (commented out CTRL+F: "string url").
Any help would be greatly appreciated!

I should mention that the I've tried sending the header as proper capitalization X-csrf-token as well as x-csrf-token to no avail.

Make sure that your cookie matches the device because Roblox limits your cookie to work on specific hardware. Changing your user agent will likely help as well.

these tokens expire. what your should do is make the request and if it gives a 403 token error it will have a token in its response header as x-csrf-token add that token to your request header and resend the request and it should work. if this didn't fix it try adding https://www.roblox.com as the Refferer header.

just send the request to whatever roblox api you wanna use and if the response code is a 403 just get the x-csrf-token response header and set it as your request header and resend the same api again.

@Yorick That would be the solution it seems except it doesn't appear that the other APIs respond with a CSRF token.
